# Group and count values of a column which is not counted before

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL in that I have a table like this.

```
id  | p_no    | date
1   | 100001  | 2015-01-01
2   | 100002  | 2015-01-01
3   | 100003  | 2015-01-01
4   | 100004  | 2015-01-01
5   | 100003  | 2015-01-02
6   | 100004  | 2015-01-02
7   | 100005  | 2015-01-02
8   | 100004  | 2015-01-03
9   | 100003  | 2015-01-03
10  | 100002  | 2015-01-03
11  | 100001  | 2015-01-03
12  | 100005  | 2015-01-04
13  | 100006  | 2015-01-04
14  | 100007  | 2015-01-04
15  | 100008  | 2015-01-04
```

From that table I want to get the **new count** of `p_no` **grouped by date**. I expect result like below.

```
date       | count
2015-01-01 | 4
2015-01-02 | 1
2015-01-03 | 0
2015-01-04 | 3
```

Which I want to count like the following.

```
id  | p_no    | date
1   | 100001  | 2015-01-01
2   | 100002  | 2015-01-01
3   | 100003  | 2015-01-01
4   | 100004  | 2015-01-01   -- new count 4
-----------------------------------------------
5   | 100003  | 2015-01-02
6   | 100004  | 2015-01-02
7   | 100005  | 2015-01-02   -- new count 1 (p_no 100003 & 100004 are already counted on the previous day)
-----------------------------------------------
8   | 100004  | 2015-01-03
9   | 100003  | 2015-01-03
10  | 100002  | 2015-01-03
11  | 100001  | 2015-01-03   -- new count 0 (because all the p_no are counted before)
-----------------------------------------------
12  | 100005  | 2015-01-04
13  | 100006  | 2015-01-04
14  | 100007  | 2015-01-04
15  | 100008  | 2015-01-04   -- new count 3 (p_no 100005 is counted before)
```

I'm have to do this by query itself without using any external script. So, please guide me for that.

Comment: I normally do group by and get the distinct count but in this case I have no idea at all.

Comment: nice question bud. we like the tough ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT g.`date`, COUNT(x.p_no) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT `date`
      FROM mytable
      GROUP by `date`) AS g
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_no, `date`
           FROM mytable AS t1
           WHERE p_no NOT IN (SELECT p_no 
                              FROM mytable AS t2
                              WHERE t2.`date` < t1.`date`)) AS x
ON g.`date` = x.`date` 
GROUP BY g.`date`
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ffe8f/7)

**Explanation**

The query performs a `LEFT JOIN` on two derived tables. The first one, `g`, comes from this query:

```
SELECT `date`
FROM mytable
GROUP by `date`
```

with *output*:

```
date
------
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
```

So, the first derived table essentially contains all dates of your initial table.

The second derived table, `x`, comes from this query:

```
SELECT p_no, `date`
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE p_no NOT IN (SELECT p_no 
                   FROM mytable AS t2
                   WHERE t2.`date` < t1.`date`)
```

with *output*:

```
p_no    date
----------------------
100001  2015-01-01
100002  2015-01-01
100003  2015-01-01
100004  2015-01-01
100005  2015-01-02
100006  2015-01-04
100007  2015-01-04
100008  2015-01-04
```

So, the second derived table essentially contains all records that we want to count.

Note that date `2015-01-03` is missing from `x` since there no `p_no` values for this date that do not exists at any prior date. This is the reason why we have to use `g` derived table and perform a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table thing1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    p_no int not null,
    theDate date not null
);
insert thing1 (p_no,theDate) values
(100001,'2015-01-01'),
(100002,'2015-01-01'),
(100003,'2015-01-01'),
(100004,'2015-01-01'),
(100003,'2015-01-02'),
(100004,'2015-01-02'),
(100005,'2015-01-02'),
(100004,'2015-01-03'),
(100003,'2015-01-03'),
(100002,'2015-01-03'),
(100001,'2015-01-03'),
(100005,'2015-01-04'),
(100006,'2015-01-04'),
(100007,'2015-01-04'),
(100008,'2015-01-04');
```

### The Query:

```
select theDate,sum(blahblah) as theCount
from
(   select t.theDate,x.p_no,
    case when x.p_no is null then 0 else 1 end as blahblah
    from thing1 t
    left join
    (  select p_no,min(theDate) as xDate
       from thing1
       group by p_no
    ) x
    on x.p_no=t.p_no and t.theDate<=x.xDate
) y
group by theDate
order by theDate
+------------+----------+
| theDate    | theCount |
+------------+----------+
| 2015-01-01 |        4 |
| 2015-01-02 |        1 |
| 2015-01-03 |        0 |
| 2015-01-04 |        3 |
+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` in combination with `WHERE t2.id IS NULL` to filter out the records you don't want to count.

```
SELECT t1.date, COUNT(*) count FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.p_no = t2.p_no AND t1.date >= t2.date AND t1.id != t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.date
```

You need to put this in a subquery to get the dates with count 0:

```
SELECT t3.date, IFNULL(j1.count,0) count FROM mytable t3 LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT t1.date, COUNT(*) count FROM mytable t1
    LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.p_no = t2.p_no AND t1.date >= t2.date AND t1.id != t2.id
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.date
) j1 ON t3.date = j1.date
GROUP BY t3.date
```

Same result is even possible without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable LEFT JOIN mytable j1 ON mytable.p_no = j1.p_no AND mytable.date > j1.date WHERE mytable.date = t1.date AND j1.id IS NULL ) 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT date FROM mytable ) t1
```